# Como poner un cargador de pagina después de enviar una petición por ajax usando jsp

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

Como se podría poner un cargador de pagina al buscar datos con jsp y mysql utilizando ajax. Necesito que se muestre un cargador de pagina cada vez que yo realice una búsqueda con ajax y aparezca el cargador antes de los datos.

Aquí dejó el código.
Esta es la función que va a un servlet llamado BuscarVuelosAjax y con url buscarVuelosAjax.do. Lo que necesito es poner un cargador de pagina que se muestre despues de presionar el botón para buscar.
He visto varios ejemplos pero no he encontrado uno que sea con jsp y servlet

```
    function buscarVuelosAjax()
{
    var fchDespegueAjax =$("#fechaDespegueAjax").val();
    var fchArriboAjax =$("#fechaArriboAjax").val();


            $.ajax({
            url:"buscarVuelosAjax.do",
            data:{
                fdespegue : fchDespegueAjax,
                farribo:fchArriboAjax
            },
            success: function( result ) {
            $( "#resultadoVuelo" ).html( result);
            }


    });


}
```

Aquí el código del servlet que muestra los datos

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    TramoVuelo tv=new TramoVuelo();
    Vuelo v = new Vuelo();
    Estacion e=new Estacion();
    Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
    VuelosDao vDao = new VuelosDao();

    tv.setFechaDespegue(request.getParameter("fdespegue"));
    tv.setFechaArribo(request.getParameter("farribo"));
    //e.setCodigoEstado(request.getParameter("txtestacion"));
    ResultSet res=(ResultSet)vDao.buscarVuelos(tv,v);
    //ResultSet res=(ResultSet)vDao.buscarVuelos(tv,v,e);
    ArrayList<Vuelo> vuelo = new ArrayList<Vuelo>();

    if(res==null || request.getParameter("fdespegue").isEmpty()|| request.getParameter("farribo").isEmpty())
    {
        String error="No se encontraron datos";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    else
    {
        try
        {
            while(res.next())
            {
                vuelo.add(new Vuelo(res.getInt("SEQ_VLOS"),res.getString("LNAR_COD_LNAR"),res.getInt("NUMERO_VLOS"),res.getDate("FECH_VLOS").toString(),res.getString("EST_VLOS"),res.getString("TPO_TRANS_VLOS"),res.getString("FCH_CRE_VLOS"),res.getString("RUTA_VLOS"),res.getString("VLO").toString()));
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("vuelo", vuelo);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("resultadoVuelos.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BuscarVuelosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<jsp:include page=\"modalBuscarVuelo.jsp\"/>");
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet BuscarVuelosAjax</title>");
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='./javascript/administradorVuelos.js'></script>");
        //out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='./javascript/detalleVueloAjaxx.js'></script>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<form method='POST' action='verCargaServlet.do'>");
        out.println("<table class='table-responsive table table-hover table-responsive' id='resultadoBusquedaVuelos'>");
        out.println("<thead>");
        out.println("<tr>");
               out.println("<th style='display:none' class='bg-primary col-sm-2'>CODIGO</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>IATA</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>Nº VUELO</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>FECHA</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>ESTADO</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>TRANSITO</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>FECHA CREACIÓN</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>RUTA</th>");
               //out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>GUIAS</th>");
               out.println("<th class='bg-primary'>ACCIÓN</th>");
      out.println("</tr>");
      out.println("</thead>");
      out.println("<tbody>");

for(int i=0; i<vuelo.size(); i++)
           {
               out.println("<tr>");
               //out.println("<td><input type='text' readonly name='txtidvuelo' size='3' id='idVuelosAjax' style='background-color:;' value="+vuelo.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"></td>");
               out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+vuelo.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"</td>");

               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getIataVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getNumeroVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getFechaVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getEstadoVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getTipoTransitoVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getFechaCreacionVuelo()+"</td>");
               out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getRutaVuelo()+"</td>");
               //out.println("<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Detalle' width=10 heigth=10></td>");
               //out.println("<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='verDetalleVueloAjax()' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalBuscarVuelos' width=10 heigth=10>Ver Detalle</button></td>");
               out.println("<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleVuelo' width=10 heigth=10 onclick('verGuiasVueloAjax()')><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button></td>");
               //out.println("<td><p><input type='checkbox' class='filled-in' id='filled-in-box'><label for='filled-in-box'>Seleccionar</label></p></td>");
               out.println("</tr>");

           }


out.println("</tbody>");
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</form>");



            out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Acá el codigo jsp donde se visualizan los datos.

```
        <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center row col-lg-12">        
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel-heading bg-primary"><h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Administrador de Carga</h4></div>
                 <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">

                <form method="POST" action="buscarVuelosServlet">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#" ><b>Fecha Despegue:</b><input type="text"  class="form-control-static" name="txtfechadespegue" id="fechaDespegueAjax"   required></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" ><b>Fecha Arribo:</b><input type="text"   class="form-control-static" name="txtfechaarribo" id="fechaArriboAjax" required></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><button type="button" name="btnbuscar" value="BUSCAR" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buscarVuelosAjax()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar</button></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><button type="button" name="btnVolver" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='barraCentral.jsp'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Atras</button></a></li>
                </ul>
                </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="resultadoVuelo">

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


    </nav>
```

Esto funciona bien, el problema que tengo es que no se como o donde colocar un cargador de pagina para que al realizar la búsqueda se muestre cargando hasta que se muestren los datos.Eh visto muchos ejemplos de cargadores de pagina pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo con ajax y servlet.
Por favor si alguien me pudiese ayudar con esto.

Comment: como sería esto?

Comment: estimados me podrían ayudar por favor con este tema.

Comment: Estimados acabo de completar la pregunta con los datos. Por favor si me pudiesen ayudar con este tema.

Comment: Estimados , como se podría hacer?

Comment: Estimados por favor si me pudieran ayudar. He estado investigando por internet pero no he encontrado ejemplo hecho con java servlet y ajax y necesito dicha funcionalidad para mi proyecto de titulo que debo presentar luego. Si tuvieran alguna forma me podrían ayudar por favor se los agradecería.